# .NET equivalent of size_t

Tags: .net, 64-bit, pinvoke

I have a piece of .NET code which I want to port to 64-bit. The codes basically is a set of P/Invoke calls to some other C dll. One of the functions in the C dll has a parameter 'size_t'. What datatype should I use in my P/Invoke signature so that the marshalling works fine. I was thinking of using a IntPtr or a UIntPtr but some say that they are a pointer equivalent thing in .NET and shouldnt be using it. Does anyone know what the correct type for this is?

Comment: What "bit-ness" is the C DLL?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

UIntPtr will work (IntPtr would probably work too, but size_t is unsigned, so UIntPtr is a better fit)

JaredPar has written something on his [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaredpar/pinvoke-with-32-and-64-bit-machines) (and a [follow-up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaredpar/follow-up-pinvoke-with-32-and-64-bit)) about this.

Answer (score 2):

As of C# v9 (which requires dotnet 5 or newer) we now have ["native sized" integer types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nint-nuint) in the form of `nint` and `nuint`, which have the same basic behaviour as `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr` respectively. This makes `nuint` an ideal type to use when a p/invoke target requires a `size_t`, without the need for the extra marshalling magic linked to in [Patrick McDonald's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/772555/1450890).

Answer (score 1):

If size_t varies depending on the platform, you'll have to use IntPtr. If it is a fixed size integer, use int, uint or long (depending on the original declaration).

Answer (score 1):

I've found a dirty hack that can help you achieve similar behavior. It requires that you define a compilation symbol `_WIN64` for your 64-bit builds and then you can do the following:

```
#if _WIN64
    using size_t = UInt64;
#else
    using size_t = UInt32;
#endif
```

Note: you will have to use the above code in every file that wants to utilize the `size_t` type.

You can also define your own integer type (much like UInt64 is defined) and reuse it without having to put the above code in every file that needs access to `size_t`, but it's very complicated (imho).

```
#if _WIN64
    using _size_t = UInt64;
#else
    using _size_t = UInt32;
#endif

[Serializable]
[CLSCompliant(false)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public struct size_t : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<_size_t>, IEquatable<_size_t>
{
    private _size_t _value;

    public size_t(_size_t val)
    {
        _value = val;
    }

    // You have to add all of your overloads below
}
```

This will allow `size_t` to change it's type depending on the platform, but correctly overloading the necessary operators is very tricky!

Comment: Having to define the compilation symbol means that this will not work for Any CPU builds, and it will crash if someone modifies the executable to run as something else(x86/x64).

Comment: @ØysteinE.Krog I agree, I also generally find that you don't really need `size_t` unless you're working with a C++ dll, so in that case you wouldn't compile with Any CPU and it should work. It's a dirty enough hack that there are very few cases that warrant using it.