# How to PInvoke CMark's cmark_markdown_to_html

Tags: c#, pinvoke, cmark

I'm trying to PInvoke the following function from GitHub's fork of CMark

```
char *cmark_markdown_to_html(const char *text, size_t len, int options)
```

and here's my PInvoke signature:

```
[DllImport("cmark.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr cmark_markdown_to_html(
        [In()] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string text, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)] uint len,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)] int options);
```

I call it as follows:

```
var retValue = cmark_markdown_to_html(markdown, 0, 0);
```

However, it throws a Marshaling exception the with the message:

```
Cannot marshal 'parameter #2': 
  Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination 
  (Int32/UInt32 must be paired with I4, U4, or Error).
```

OK, so I change the signature to:

```
[DllImport("cmark.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr cmark_markdown_to_html(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string text, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint len,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int options);
```

Now it throws a `PInvokeStackImbalance` error

```
The name '$exception' does not exist in the current context
```

Native stuff is a mystery to me. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PInvokeStackImbalance

Presumably CMark is using the default calling convention. The default calling convention for C code is "Cdecl", while the default used for P/invoke calls is "StdCall". The calling convention specifies how the arguments and return value are placed on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). A mismatch between the used calling convention causes the stack to become imbalanced.

You can specify the calling convention to use from C# code in the `DllImport` attribute.

```
[DllImport("cmark.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr cmark_markdown_to_html(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string text, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint len,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int options);
```

#### Marshalling

In case you want your code to be compatible with architectures other than 32-bit, you would want to marshall `size_t` with `UIntPtr`. (Read @Eugene Podskal answer)

```
[DllImport("cmark.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr cmark_markdown_to_html(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string text, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UIntPtr len,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int options);
```

Then you can call the method like so

```
var retValue = cmark_markdown_to_html(markdown, UIntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Stack imbalance

The reason for stack imbalance is described in [Why are Cdecl calls often mismatched in the "standard" P/Invoke Convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660722/why-are-cdecl-calls-often-mismatched-in-the-standard-p-invoke-convention).

Basically you need to specify proper calling convention in the `DllImport` that will probably be `cdecl`:

```
[DllImport("cmark.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

#### Marshalling size_t

That one is discussed in [what is equal to the c++ size_t in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906774/what-is-equal-to-the-c-size-t-in-c-sharp) .

- Assuming that CMark will always be native (32 bit on x86, 64 bit on x64), you should use `(U)IntPtr`.
- If it is always 32 bit, then `Int32` should be used.

Comment: I remember the calling convention thing now that you mention it. Haven't had to PInvoke in a long time.Marked the first one as the answer since that was the first answer. Yours is equally valid.